# Curious CSS: "font-family: restore-n8;"

Tags: css, fonts

Found some curious CSS in the source for http://contrastrebellion.com/:

```
font-family: restore-n8, restore-1, restore-2, sans-serif;
```

`Restore-n8` and the like don't seem to be font names. What does this CSS snippet do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's [Restore](http://typekit.com/fonts/restore), served by TypeKit.

These fonts have been included using CSS3's `@font-face`. The fonts themselves have been included in the styles, using base-64 encoding, and can be referenced like any other font family in CSS once defined.

Here's a quick example of the CSS that defines one of those fonts:

```
@font-face {
font-family:"restore-1";
src:url(data:font/opentype;base64,d09GRk--snip--gAA);
font-style:normal;
font-weight:300;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Tried to do a search on it, but it seems like you can only use font-family for font families. Therefore i will assume that restore-n8 actually is a font (probably one that they made themselves). I suppose it's also possible that they used some tool to create the css and it failed somehow and spit out that line.
don't know what else it could be.

Comment: The interesting thing is that the text does show up with a non-standard font... I was actually trying to determine the font in the first place :)